# Parse nested xml with jQuery (children elements)

Tags: jquery, xml

First off here is the structure I'm going for:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <h3>State Name 1</h3>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <a href="storeurl" id="storeid">storename</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="storeurl" id="storeid">storename2</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <h3>State Name 2</h3>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <a href="storeurl" id="storeid">storename</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Here's how my xml file is structured:

```
<storeList>
    <state>
        <stateName>Maine</stateName>
            <store>
                <storeName>first store</storeName>
                <storeID>store1</storeID>
                <storeURL>http://www.url.com</storeURL>
            </store>
            <store>
                <storeName>second store</storeName>
                <storeID>store2</storeID>
                <storeURL>http://www.url.com</storeURL>
            </store>
            <store>
                <storeName>third store</storeName>
                <storeID>store3</storeID>
                <storeURL>http://www.url.com</storeURL>
            </store>
    </state>
    <state>
        <stateName>Connecticut</stateName>
            <store>
                <storeName>first store</storeName>
                <storeID>store4</storeID>
                <storeURL>http://www.url.com</storeURL>
            </store>
    </state>
</storeList>
```

I'm not sure how to loop through the elements to get the nested list.
I know how to write xml elements to the html, but I haven't done this type of nested list before.

I tried breaking up the script to loop through the different elements, but this didn't work and I know my structure is wrong for the second part. I'm assuming I'll have to do some sort of outer or inner wrap of the ul elements?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                          $.ajax({
                              type: "GET",
                              url: "xml/storeList.xml",
                              dataType: "xml",
                              success: xmlParser
                          });
                          });

                          function xmlParser(xml) {

                          $(xml).find("state").each(function () {

                              $(".storeListContent").append('<ul><li><h3>' +
                                $(this).find("stateName").text() +
                                '</h3></li></ul>');



                          });

                            /*$(xml).find("store").each(function () {
                           $(".storeListContent ul li").append('<ul><li>' +
                                '<a class="storeInactive" id="' +
                                $(this).find("storeID").text() +
                                '" href="' +
                                $(this).find("stateURL").text() +
                                '">' +
                                $(this).find("stateName").text() +
                                '</a>' +
                                '</li></ul>'
                                );
                            });*/

                          }
```

***Working:***
Had to change the datatype to html instead of xml.
Anyone have insight into why that works?

Comment: Do you have access to the server code?  It might be a LOT easier to do this manipulation on the server using XSLT... and then get the html string already prepared.

Comment: No, needing to run it all frontend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my updated code.
Had to change the `dataType` to `"html"`.
Not sure why that works.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xml/storeList.xml",
        dataType: "html",
        success: xmlParser
    });
});

function xmlParser(xml) {
    $(".storeListContent").append("<ul>");
    $(xml).find('state').each(function () {

        $(".storeListContent").append("<li><h3>" + $(this).find("stateName").text() + "</h3><ul>");

        $(this).find("store").each(function (i, e) {
            $(".storeListContent").append("<li><a class='storeInactive' id='" + $(e).find("storeID").text() + "' href='" + $(e).find("storeURL").text() + "'>" + $(e).find("storeName").text() + "</a></li>");
        });
        $(".storeListContent").append("</ul></li>");
    });
    $(".storeListContent").append("</ul>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your XML is located in a file called **"store.xml"**

```
$.get('store.xml', null, function (data) {
    document.write("<ul>");
    $(data).find('state').each( function(){

        document.write("<li><h3>" + $(this).find("stateName").text() + "</h3><ul>");

        $(this).find("store").each(function(i,e){
            document.write("<li><a class='storeInactive' id='" +    $(e).find("storeID").text() + "' href='" + $(e).find("storeURL").text() + "'>" + $(e).find("storeName").text() + "</a></li>");
        });
        document.write("</ul></li>");
    });
    document.write("</ul>");
}, 'xml');
```

### OUTPUT:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h3>Maine</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="storeInactive" id="store1" href="http://www.url.com">first store</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="storeInactive" id="store2" href="http://www.url.com">second store</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="storeInactive" id="store3" href="http://www.url.com">third store</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Connecticut</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="storeInactive" id="store4" href="http://www.url.com">first store</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**

For your reference I have added whole html, which I have written on my machine which is working fine.

### HTML File:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" > 

$.get('xml/store.xml', null, function (data) { 
    document.write("<ul>"); 
    $(data).find('state').each( function(){ 
        document.write("<li><h3>" + $(this).find("stateName").text() + "</h3><ul>"); 
    $(this).find("store").each(function(i,e){ 
        document.write("<li><a class='storeInactive' id='" + $(e).find("storeID").text() + "' href='" + $(e).find("storeURL").text() + "'>" + $(e).find("storeName").text() + "</a></li>"); 
    }); 
    document.write("</ul></li>"); 
    }); 
    document.write("</ul>"); 
}, 'xml'); 

</script>
```

Comment: It will work and have tested it on **firefox** & **IE**, i think you are missing something. Have you place your xml file and your html in the same folder? It should be something like **store.xml** and **store.html**

Comment: my xml is in xml/storelist.xml and I've adjusted your code accordingly. I put the script inline where I want the output, and it doesn't return anything for me.

Comment: can you tell me on which browser your testing & also let me know how you merged the code? I suspect still you are missing some thing...

Comment: ' $(document).ready(function () {
 $.get('xml/storeList.xml', null, function (data) {
    document.write("<ul>");
    $(data).find('state').each( function(){

        document.write("<li><h3>" + $(this).find("stateName").text() + "</h3><ul>");

        $(this).find("store").each(function(i,e){
            document.write("<li><a class='storeInactive' id='" +    $(e).find("storeID").text() + "' href='" + $(e).find("storeURL").text() + "'>" + $(e).find("storeName").text() + "</a></li>");
        });
        document.write("</ul></li>");
    });
    document.write("</ul>");
}, 'xml');
});
'

Comment: remove this line `$(document).ready(function () {` and closing line `});`. Place only **`$.get`** part of code.

Comment: I even added this to a blank html doc, with jquery and it's not writing data to the page

Comment: I have updated whole html in my answer, which I have tested on firefox & IE.

Comment: this just cycles for me and never outputs