# How to get xml all child node value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, xml-parsing

I have a xml that xml contains folder and image details.I load a xml using jquery and i got folder details but the image path not getting properly now i am getting

**images/ftest1.png,images/fstest1.png,images/fsstest1.png,images/stest1.png,images/sstest1.png**

how to get all?

**Mycode**

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#dvContent").append("<ul></ul>");
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "books.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
        $(xml).find("FolderName").each(function(index, element){ 
        var levels = $(this).parents("OrgFolderDetails").size();
        var text = $(this).attr('name');
        var text1 = $(this).text();
        var html = "";
        //alert($(this).find("child[value='"+text+"']"));
        //alert($(this).children().size())
        var level_child=$(this).children().size();
        for(var j=0; j < level_child; j++){
            alert($(this).children().attr('path'));
        }
        for(var j=0; j < levels; j++){
            html += "-";  

        }


        html += "<li> "+text+"</li>"; //add in that space after the dashes, and the <br>

        $("#browser").append(html);
    });
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
      }
      });
    });
```

**Xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <OrgFolderDetails>
      <FolderName name="Main Folder"></FolderName>
      <TheChildren>
      <OrgFolderDetails>
        <FolderName name="First Sub Folder">
          <source path="images/ftest1.png"></source>
          <source path="images/ftest2.png"></source>
          <source path="images/ftest3.png"></source>
          <source path="images/ftest4.png"></source>
          <source path="images/ftest5.png"></source>
        </FolderName>
        <TheChildren>
        <OrgFolderDetails>
          <FolderName name="First Sub Siub Sub Folder">
            <source path="images/fstest1.png"></source>
            <source path="images/fstest2.png"></source>
            <source path="images/fstest3.png"></source>
            <source path="images/fstest4.png"></source>
            <source path="images/fstest5.png"></source>
          </FolderName>
          <TheChildren>
          <OrgFolderDetails>
            <FolderName name="First Sub Siub Sub Folder">
              <source path="images/fsstest1.png"></source>
              <source path="images/fsstest2.png"></source>
              <source path="images/fsstest3.png"></source>
              <source path="images/fsstest4.png"></source>
              <source path="images/fsstest5.png"></source>
            </FolderName>
            <TheChildren>
            <OrgFolderDetails>
              <FolderName name="First Sub Sub Sub Sub Folder"></FolderName>
              <TheChildren/>
            </OrgFolderDetails>
            </TheChildren>
          </OrgFolderDetails>
          </TheChildren>
        </OrgFolderDetails>
        </TheChildren>
      </OrgFolderDetails>
      <OrgFolderDetails>
        <FolderName name="Second Sub Folder">
          <source path="images/stest1.png"></source>
          <source path="images/stest2.png"></source>
          <source path="images/stest3.png"></source>
          <source path="images/stest4.png"></source>
          <source path="images/stest5.png"></source>
        </FolderName>
        <TheChildren>
        <OrgFolderDetails>
          <FolderName name="Second Sub Sub Folder">
            <source path="images/sstest1.png"></source>
            <source path="images/sstest2.png"></source>
            <source path="images/sstest3.png"></source>
            <source path="images/sstest4.png"></source>
            <source path="images/sstest5.png"></source>
          </FolderName>
          <TheChildren/>
        </OrgFolderDetails>
        </TheChildren>
      </OrgFolderDetails>
      </TheChildren>
    </OrgFolderDetails>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need an XML parser. You could use anything from jquery, js or say some perl cgi scripts to get this job done. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049059/how-to-read-all-the-child-elements-of-an-element-using-jquery), I think it best answers your question (chk the answers well) Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417980/parse-nested-xml-with-jquery-children-elements) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417980/parse-nested-xml-with-jquery-children-elements) might help you a bit as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this XPath expression ~//source[@path]~ over that xml file then you will get a list of all source elements that contains path attribute. Then you can get all the images from the result.